# Looking up names in other tables(SQL)

Tags: sql

I have two tables

Applied_Uni

```
   StudentID University1Code University2Code University3Code
   1          U1              U2              U3
   2          U1              U2              U4
```

University

```
UniversityCode UniversityName
U1             School1
U2             School2
U3             School3
U4             School4
```

The problem I'm having is I don't know how to write sql to select students with university names they are applied into.

Any kind help is appreciated.

Comment: Any queries you tried ? Try to make a sqlfiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to join on itself:

```
SELECT AU.StudentId, 
    U.UniversityName Name1,
    U2.UniversityName Name2,
    U3.UniversityName Name3
FROM Applied_Uni AU
    LEFT JOIN University U ON AU.University1Code = U.UniversityCode
    LEFT JOIN University U2 ON AU.University2Code = U2.UniversityCode
    LEFT JOIN University U3 ON AU.University3Code = U3.UniversityCode
```

Alternatively, this should work:

```
SELECT AU.StudentId, 
    U.UniversityName 
FROM Applied_Uni AU
    LEFT JOIN University U ON 
         AU.University1Code = U.UniversityCode
         OR AU.University2Code = U.UniversityCode
         OR AU.University3Code = U.UniversityCode
```